# Can't access Object

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

I have a circle as movieclip in the settings and a fex controlls (up,down,left,right).

I dropped all controlls and the circle and press on a button to add some actionscript.

I inserted:

```
on (release)
{
    _root.Kreis0._x -=10;
}
```

the circle is called Kreis0.

When i click on the controll nothing happen

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work. Make sure the `Kreis0` is the instance of the movieClip , not the name of the symbol.

I just tried your example and it works awesome. If you want it , i could send you the .FLA

Answer (score 0):

There could be a lot of things wrong. It's hard to say with the information you've given. But..

Is `Kreis0` the name of the symbol in the library? When you add the symbol to the stage, you have to give it an instance name in order to access it.

Also, the symbol must be a MovieClip or a Button, it can't be a graphic.